# Discord bot (on_message event wont let commands working *)

Tags: python, discord

Been browsing to fix this issue and actually tried to insert bot.process_commands(message) into my code but it doesn't seem to be helping. Here's the code so far. Only the on_message event does work while the command doesn't.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user == message.author:
        return
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    if message.content.startswith('hello') and str(message.channel) != 'images':
        await  message.channel.send('Hi')
    if str(message.channel) == 'images' and message.content != '':
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
    
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
        return
    raise error

@bot.command()
async def Hamdii (ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

    
bot.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is check for the command inside the on_message() event, like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    if bot.user == message.author:
        return

    message.content = message.content.lower()

    if message.content.startswith('hello') and str(message.channel) != 'images':
        await  message.channel.send('Hi')

    if str(message.channel) == 'images' and message.content != '':
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)

    if message.content.startswith('/hamdii'):
        await message.channel.send(message.content[7:])
```

Comment: Personally, I don't know a single usage that this is not gonna work. If you want to make the script better organized you should try divide it into cogs